# Not able to pass schema of the json record dynamically to spark structured streaming records

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have a Spark-Kakfa-Strucutre streaming pipeline. Listening to a topic, which may have json records of varying schema.
Now I want to resolve the schema based on the key(x_y), and then apply to value portion to parse the json record.
So here key's 'y' part tells about the schema type.
I tried to get the schema string from udf and then pass to from_json() function.
But it fails with exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Schema should be specified in DDL format as a string literal or output of the schema_of_json function instead of `schema`
```

Code used:

```
df.withColumn("data_type", element_at(split(col("key").cast("string"),"_"),1))
.withColumn("schema", schemaUdf($"data_type"))
.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), col("schema")).as("data"))
```

Schema demo:

```
    {
  "type" : "struct",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "name",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "struct",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "firstname",
        "type" : "string",
        "nullable" : true,
        "metadata" : { }
      }]
    },
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  } ]
}
```

UDF used:

```
lazy val fetchSchema = (fileName : String) => {
    DataType.fromJson(mapper.readTree(new File(fileName)).toString)
  }
val schemaUdf = udf[DataType, String](fetchSchema)
```

Note: I am not using confluent feature.

Comment: can you share the content (example) of your `"schema"` column?

Comment: @Amit, from the error message itself it is clear that you cannot use `col("schema")`. Instead you can use `schema_of_json(col("schema"))` as the error message suggests. btw, i hope you are using Spark 3.0

Comment: @mazaneicha, Unfortunately, the schema is big, so I cannot share it. It is a nested json records, so pls consider the schema as per.

Comment: @SathiyanS, I am using 2.4.5. Not sure if that will make a difference.
I have already tried schema_of_json(col("schema")), it did not work out. It looks like down the layer, it only resolves, string literals, udf is not entertained.

Comment: Sorry, version makes no difference here! by the way can you share what you are doing inside `schemaUDF`?  what is the type of `schema` variable? also what you are getting when you are passing `schema_of_json`?

Comment: @mazaneicha Added the demo schema in the question.